# CollapsingToolbarLayout igual ao Nubank

Tags: android, xml

Olá,

Gostaria de saber como fazer o design do CollapsingToolbarLayout igual ao do Nubank. Esse abaixo:

[image: Banco Nubank]
[image: Banco Nubank]

O código abaixo é o que tentei fazer, porém ele não funciona o colapso corretamente.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/appbar_layout_activity"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.zionshell.ste.ui.activity.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="35.548 pts"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:textSize="33sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="3.542 pontos acumulados nos últimos 7 dias"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:windowContentOverlay="@null"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coupons_lst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Abaixo o resultado:

[image: Sistema de Pontuação usando CollapsingToolbarLayout]
  [image: Sistema de Pontuação usando CollapsingToolbarLayout]